# Creating a login table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design

My objective is to create a table that stores the information of the users and their passwords. Also, I want to keep track the number of failed logins. However, Here is a brief description about the tables:

**First: the table of users**

UserNo: ID of the user

Name: user's name

Email

**Second: the table of login**

UserNo: is the same as the last one

Password

**Third: the table of tracking**

UserNo

DateTime: date and time of login

count: counter that increases every time the user logins incorrectly.

From the last three tables, I do not think what I have done is a professional way. Is there any better ideas? especially with the tracking table.

Thanks

Comment: I would really consider just putting it all in one table. Reset the failed counter upon successful login and only keep track of date and time of most previous unless you need to keep track of all of them.

Comment: Why do you think it is not professional?  You could put the password in table 1 and do away with table 2, do you get a record in table 3 each time a user logs in?  If not, this too could be merged into the first table, i.e. and use LastSuccessfulLoginDate

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points:

1. There's no reason for your second table unless you're going to keep a password history (in which case you need an additional field to track the date the password was created)
2. In the third table, don't use a counter for the number of incorrect logins; instead, write a record for every login attempt (successful or otherwise), and use a query to retrieve the count whenever you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you keeping them separate? Why not just have a users table with the id, username, password hash, last login date and failed attempts counter?

Otherwise you could separate out login attempts to it's own table and record a status e.g. SUCCESS or FAIL so you can procedurally calculate number of failed attempts since the last successful one, and it also provides a full audit of logins, failed or not.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to merge the first two tables together, as there is only one password per user, so it makes sense to have all the data for a user on one row in one table.

The third table records the timestamp of each login, and could also record the timestamp of each failed login if you added an extra column, then a quesy will give you a count of total failed logins per user.

Or, if you are counting the number of failed logins since last login, then you could just put the counter in the first table again.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your fields in a single table

```
UserID, UserName, UserEmail, Password, Login_Timestamp, Counter
```

then you can save all the values in a single table